# Create a sysprep provider with C#

Tags: c#, windows

My app needs to write a regkey if the Windows machine it is installed on runs SysPrep.

According to http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee676646(WS.10).aspx#SysprepDevGuide_RegisteringYourSysprepProvider the "SysPrep Provider" has to be a DLL.

As my app is written in C# (I'm a beginner developer), I can't seem to export a function that can be run via RunDLL32 when using C#. While it would be very easy for me to create a simple console application, it appears SysPrep can only accept a DLL, not an executable program. Is there a way that I can create a sysprep provider in C#, or do I have to write the provider in C++ (a language I don't know).

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: DLLs and win32 executables are basically the same, as far as I know. The executable just has an entry point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way of doing this would be to write a C++/CLI wrapper (mixed mode dll) that calls into your managed dll, but if you want to avoid C++ it seems a guy called Robert Giesecke whipped up a library for exporting managed functions allowing them to be called just like a regular C functions.

Check this out: https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports

Apparently this gives you a DllExport attribute which seems to be as easy to use as DllImport:

```
class Test
{
    [DllExport( "add", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl )]
    public static int TestExport( int left, int right )
    {
        return left + right;
    } 
}
```

The download and some more information can be found here: https://nuget.org/packages/UnmanagedExports